# having " Response stream has already been completed" when the server use WriteAsync method

Tags: c#, grpc

I get "Response stream has already been completed." when the server call WriteAsync() method by using pi-stream.Only when I use Thread.sleep the client sometimes can get the stream during the sleeping time.But I know that's not the solution.So plz tell me what can I do!

I used .net core 2.2 and vs community 2019 16.2.3

```
                proto:
                rpc CppyFile(stream Chunk)returns(stream Back){}

                message Chunk{
                bytes Content=1;
                string FileName=2;
                string Flag=3;
                }

                message Back{
                bytes Content=1;
                UploadStatus statue=2;
                string Flag=3;
                }


                Server:
                await responseStream.WriteAsync(new Back
                            {
                                Content = ByteString.FromStream(stream),
                                Flag = fname,
                                Statue = new UploadStatus
                                {
                                    Message = "2",
                                    Code = UploadStatusCode.Unknown
                                }
                            });


                client:

                using (var call = client.CppyFile())
            {

                try
                {
                    await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(chunk);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending");

                        //################################################################################## here's Problem

                        await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
                    //Thread.Sleep(8 * 1000);
                        //##################################################################################

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }

                 var responseReaderTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                { 
                    while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
                    {
                        var note = call.ResponseStream.Current;    
                                        //get sending from server
                                        ......
```

here's the detail error.

System.InvalidOperationException: Response stream has already been completed.
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCallServer`2.CheckSendAllowedOrEarlyResult() in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\AsyncCallServer.cs:line 195
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCallBase`2.SendMessageInternalAsync(TWrite msg, WriteFlags writeFlags) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\AsyncCallBase.cs:line 124

Comment: Please provide your code which leads to errors.

Comment: Is this possibly https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13943?